# How should I respond to unfriendly comments by moderators?

Tags: discussion, comments, flags, moderators, offensive

I recently saw an unfriendly comment from a diamond moderator on an SE site. I would flag the comment as unfriendly or unkind if a regular user had posted it. How should I respond considering that it's from a mod?

(This is unrelated to the strike.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Flag it anyway!

On the sites I moderate, if something posted by a moderator gets flagged, that mod will recuse themself from handling it (and in fact will usually ping the rest in a private chat room to get as many other mod eyes on it as possible).

If a single mod seems to be abusing their power by wrongly declining all flags against them, you can bring it up on Meta (with specific examples of the inappropriate content): either the per-site meta, or here if necessary.

Comment: Or as a last resort, escalate to Community Managers using the "contact" option in the footer. They're ultimately responsible for oversight of diamond moderators, and can step in if necessary in case of real moderator power abuse.